# $α :( a, b, c)^T → (a − b, a + 2b + c, −2a + b − c)^T$. Find the eigenvalues of $α$ and, for each eigenvalue, find the associated eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, linear-transformations

Define $α ∈ End(R^3)$ by $α :(
a,
b,
c)^T
→
(a − b,
a + 2b + c,
−2a + b − c)^T$. Find the eigenvalues of $α$
and, for each eigenvalue, find the associated eigenspace.

I know that I need to solve $\alpha x=\lambda x$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x=(a,b,c)^T$. However, I can't cancel out any of the variables to solve explicitly for $\lambda$. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your eigenvectors are (-1,1,1),(-1,-2,7),(-1,0,1)

The related eigenspaces are sp(-1,1,1) sp(-1,-2,7) and sp(-1,0,1).

The eigenvalues are respectively 2, -1 and 1.

Comment: How did you get these values? Also, how are these eigenvalues when their 3-tuples instead of scalars?

Comment: Thank you for the solution, is there any way you could show/explain how you obtained those three eigenvalues?